# Trying to compare cells in a column to an array and hide the row of the cell if it does not match

Tags: excel, vba

As the title says, I have list of 1800 names that i'm trying to narrow down by the number of times they appear. So I have made a macro to count them, a macro that hides any that appear less than 50 times and a macro that copy's that visible list to Sheet1. so far, so good. now with this macro i want to assign list from sheet1 to an array, unhide the name list and rehide everyone who didn't make the list. and i have been using VBA for about a week total so if you have an easier idea of how to do this let me know.

```
Function in_array(my_array, my_value) As Boolean
Dim i As Variant
    For i = LBound(my_array) To UBound(my_array)
        If my_array(i) = my_value Then
            in_array = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End Function

Sub UnHideRows()

Dim cell As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim arr As Variant
Dim steve As Variant


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

arr = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A20")

'Range("E7:E1800").EntireRow.Hidden = False
For Each cell In Range("E7:E1800")
    steve = in_array(arr, cell)
        If steve = True Then
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Else
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next cell

 '   If cell.Value = arr.Value Then
 '       cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
 '   Else
 '   cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
 '   End If
'Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I am getting a subscript out of range error on the If line of my function.

Thanks so much!

Comment: You are passing a two dimensional array but only treating it like a one dimension array in the function.

Comment: Is one column not the same thing as one dimension?

Comment: No. It is a two dimensional array with one column and as many rows as the data.

Comment: Is there a change i can make to make it search the array as i would like?

Answer (score 0):

You just need a few edits:

```
Function in_array(my_array, my_value) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(my_array, 1) To UBound(my_array, 1)
        If my_array(i, 1) = my_value Then
            in_array = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

And you can simplify the rest:

```
For Each cell In Range("E7:E1800").Cells
    cell.EntireRow.Hidden = Not in_array(arr, cell.Value)
Next cell
```